# Tanstack Query - Check when data are changing inside a mutation

Tags: javascript, tanstack

I have a mutation and I would like to know if there is a way to know that the data of `installedBuckets` are changing ?
Like for example `isLoading` or something like that ?

mutation :

```js
const useUninstallBucket = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { mutate, isLoading: isMutating } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (bucketName: string) => uninstallBucket(bucketName),
    onSuccess(bucket) {
      queryClient.setQueryData(["availableBuckets"], (buckets: any) => [
        ...buckets,
        bucket,
      ]);
      queryClient.setQueryData(["installedBuckets"], (buckets: any) => [
        ...buckets.filter((b: string) => b !== bucket),
      ]);
    },
  });
  return { mutate, isMutating };
};
```

installedBuckets query :

```js
const useInstalledBuckets = () => {
  const {
    isLoading,
    data: buckets,
    error,
  } = useQuery(["installedBuckets"], getInstalledBuckets);
  return { isLoading, buckets, error };
};
```

Comment: What's wrong with `isLoading` or `isFetching`?

Comment: `isLoading` does not set to `true` when `setQueryData` is changing the values

Comment: Why would you need that? The data will be available in the next render cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that could face the same problem as me, here is the solution I found :

```js
const isMutatingBuckets = useIsMutating({ mutationKey: ["installedBuckets"] });
```

From the [documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useIsMutating)